# submitting a form with link

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have following form structure

```
<form action="{Basket-Addproduct}" method="post" id="items-form">
    <button class="button-text button-gray-custom" type="submit" value="Submit" name="{dynamically generated name}"><span>Submit</span></button>
</form>
```

here "dynamically generated name" is the key field which tells which element or product to submit..
I want it to convert it into link,
I have tried following

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('items-form').submit()" name="{dynamically generated name}">Add This </a>
```

Its getting submitted but not able to add the product...
Its expecting the name parameter also to be passed so it knows which product to add...
Stuck....:(
Any solution appreciated...

Comment: Shouldn't you wrap everything inside a `<form />`

Comment: Where is `id="items-form"`?

Answer (score 2):

you should have `<input type="submit"`.

There is no need to do JavaScript.

Just remove JS and then have as many `<input type="submit"` buttons as you want.
The GET/POST should have the key/value you look for.

E.g.

```
<input type="submit" name="item1" value="submit" />
```

when you click it, the recipient receives (sorry PHP used here):

```
$_GET['item1'] = submit
```

and other submits do not have value.

Comment: OP is asking for a method to use a link to submit a form. `<input type="submit">` is the obvious choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to do this clean and easy.

So, here's your link:

```
<a id="form-submit-btn" href="#" name="{dynamically generated name}">Add This</a>
```

And your form:

```
<form action="{Basket-Addproduct}" method="post" id="items-form">
    <!-- form contents -->
</form>
```

Now write a JavaScript which submits your form data on a button click:

```
$('#form-submit-btn').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $form = $('#items-form');
  $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(data){
    // do something with the data
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, I have created an example for you to test, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/yFWzE/

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="something" id="something" />
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit();">Submit</a>
```

By using this you will submit the form using the id of it. And other user told you to use jQuery, which I am afraid you don't want to. In jQuery you use `.preventDefault` but if you want to stick to the simple JS then you will be using `href="#"` which will automatically prevent any anchor tag execution.

And the result of the request can be checked, which sadly is an error. But it makes sure that the request has been sent to the server.

Then you can test the methods and other type of executions by having some `if else` blocks as

```
if(condition == true) {
  // if post
} else {
  // if get
}
```

The parameter might be mis handled on the server side, because when the form is submitted you need to take out the data from the QueryString (the request is GET). So, you need to check that, or if that's not the issue then make sure you're pointing the element well. Otherwise if there is no such element, nothing will be sent.

I am not sure, which language you're using but here is the code for ASP.NET

```
var value = Request.QueryString["something"];
```

PHP version is already present above. That all depends on the parameters you send with the request. You are more likely to convert the code to a function. Such as

```
<a href="#" onclick="submit()">Submit</a>
```

And the function

```
function submit() {
  // create variable
  var value = document.getElementById("something").value;\
  // now submit the form and all that other bla bla, which 
  // you want to be process, 
}
```

If you find this one tricky, using jQuery as

```
var values = $('form').serialize();
```

will be easy. This will create a string of the form and will send it with the request.